# Determinant of $A_{2n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Determine the determinant of $$A_{2n}:=\begin{pmatrix}
a &0  &\cdots   & \cdots &0  &b \\ 
 0& a &  &  &  b&0 \\ 
 \vdots &\vdots  &\ddots   &\ddots  &\vdots  &\vdots \\ 
 \vdots&\vdots  &  \ddots & \ddots  &\vdots  &\vdots  \\ 
 0& b &  &  &  a&0 \\ 
 b&0  &\cdots   &\cdots   &0  &a 
\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}$$

My initial thought is if we assume that it is $2 \times 2$, then we will get $a^2-b^2$. If it is a $4 \times 4$ one then we would get $(a^2-b^2)^2$. So would the determinant for a $2n \times 2n$ is $(a^2-b^2)^n$? But how to prove it mathematically?

Comment: No, when the matrix is 4x4, the determinant is not $a^4-b^4$ but $(a^2-b^2)^2$. When the matrix is 2nx2n, the determinant is $(a^2-b^2)^n$. Just reorder the basis to $\{e_1,e_{2n},e_2,e_{2n-2},\ldots,e_n,e_{n+1}\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Block matrix determinant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_determinant). If the blocks are square matrices of the ''same'' size further formulas hold. For example, if $C$ and $D$ commute  (i.e., $CD=DC$), then
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}A& B\\ C& D\end{pmatrix} = \det(AD - BC)$$
Thus, you can simply use induction on $n$ to prove what you suspect to be a property.

Comment: Is induction appropriate here? Your formula looks like it solves the problem outright.

Answer (score 2):

We expand the determinant along the first row:
$$
\det A_{2n}=aM_{11}+(-1)^{2n+1}bM_{1,2n}
$$
Now we expand $M_{11}$ and $M_{1,2n}$ along the last row:
$$
\det A_{2n}=a^2\det A_{2n-2}-b^2\det A_{2n-2}=(a^2-b^2)\det A_{2n-2}.
$$
Now induction works:
$$
\det A_{2n}=(a^2-b^2)(a^2-b^2)^{n-1}=(a^2-b^2)^n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\vert A_{2n}\vert=\begin{vmatrix} B_{n} & C_{n} \\ C_{n} & B_{n} \end{vmatrix}$, Where $B_{n}=aI_{n}$ and $C_{n}=bI_{n}$. Because $B_{n}$ and $C_{n}$ non singular, then

$\vert A_{2n}\vert=\vert B_{n}^2-C_{n}^2\vert=\vert a^2I_{n}-b^2I_{n}\vert=\vert (a^2-b^2)I_{n}\vert=(a^2-b^2)^n.1=(a^2-b^2)^n.$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: While I can't fault $\vert A_{2n}\vert=\begin{vmatrix} B_{n} & C_{n} \\ C_{n} & B_{n} \end{vmatrix}$ as a true statement, do remember that $A_{2n} \neq \begin{pmatrix} B_{n} & C_{n} \\ C_{n} & B_{n} \end{pmatrix}$, as the $C_n$s have the $b$s on their main diagonal (from top left to bottom right), which is not the case in the matrix $A_{2n}$.

Comment: Sorry. $C_{n}=bJ_{n}$. And, $J_{n}^2=I_{n}$. Thank you.