# Determinants with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> 1. Find the value of the determinant of
>    $$
>      A_{2n} =
>      \begin{pmatrix}
>        a      & 0      & \cdots & \cdots & 0      & b \\
>        0      & a      & \cdots & \cdots & b      & 0 \\
>        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & ⋰      & \vdots & \vdots \\
>        \vdots & \vdots & ⋰      & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
>        0      & a      & \cdots & \cdots & b      & 0 \\
>        a      & 0      & \cdots & \cdots & 0      & b
>      \end{pmatrix}
>      ∈
>      \mathbb{R}^{2n × 2n} \,.
>    $$
>    ([Original scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77CaQ.png))
> 2. Determine the value of the determinant of the matrix
>    $$
>      \begin{pmatrix}
>        a      & b      & \cdots & \cdots & b      \\
>        b      & a      & \ddots &        & \vdots \\
>        \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>        \vdots &        & \ddots & a      & b      \\
>        b      & \cdots & \cdots & b      & a
>      \end{pmatrix}
>    $$
>    ([Original scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ75V.png))

**Comment.** I was thinking that all values of the matrix that are not on the diagonal or counterdiagonal should be zero. And should I also accept $a$ for $b$ as $0$ or $1$? I would be very happy if you can help me to solve it.

thanks in advance

Comment: See [Determinant of A2n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597826/) to compute the first determinant.

Answer (score 1):

Computation of the determinant of matrix $B$.

Let's perform the following operations with rows and columns one by one:

1. Moving from top to bottom, subtract from each previous row the next one.
2. Then moving from left to right, add the previous column to the next one.

The result is a triangular matrix whose determinant is equal to the product of diagonal elements $(a-b)^{n-1}(a+(n-1)b)$.